# c# wpf datagrid clicked event and getting row value

Tags: c#, datagrid

How to do this? I want an Clicked-event-handler that triggers whenever I clicked a row. and also how can I get all the columns' values of the selected row. 
Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement an event handler for the selection changed event on the DataGrid

```
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMaster" SelectionChanged="dataGridMaster_SelectionChanged">
```

As far as getting the column values of the selected row, a lot depends what you have bound the data grid to.  For example if you have bound the DataGrid to a DataTable then here is how you would access the column values for the selected row in the event handler.

```
    private void dataGridMaster_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DataRowView rv in e.AddedItems)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Row contents:");
            foreach (object d in rv.Row.ItemArray)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\t" + d.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I binded it in List<object>. How can I specifically get the cell value by Column Name. Example in WF is row.Cells["Schedule ID"].Value.ToString();

Comment: What is object?  You get the object in e.AddedItems.  Simply get the column value from the object.  You know how it was bound to the data grid column.

I think what you are asking for is the actual rendering of the value in the cell on the DataGrid.  This is very hard to get because you have to know how the column is implemented.   For example if you have a DataGridTextColumn, the render is done in a TextBlock which is a child of a ContentPresenter which is a child of a Border which is a child of a DataGridCell .  So you can do it...but why?  Just get the value from the object itself.